# payment page cant postback to the site from authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am working in php for payment intigration when I am using the authorize.net for card transaction the URl must be stuck on the dll page but no response on url by POST method or GET method .

Comment: We're going to need more then that. What API are you using? What have you done to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I am using Direct Post method for authorize.net and my data will submit on the authorize server but the transaction information is not returning by the authorize.net server